# MySQL very slow join queries

Tags: mysql

I have following two tables in MySQL (MariaDB 6.1.7601)

```
Table: PT

+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| p_id          | char(32)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| ps_id         | int(3)        | NO   |     | NULL    |
..other 27 fields
```

This table has index on (p_id, ps_id)

Number of records: 19 million

```
Table: PF

+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| p_id          | char(32)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
..other 22 fields
```

Number of records: 19 million

I want to,

```
1) Select all records exist in PT but not in PF
2) Select all records exist in PF but not in PT
3) Select all records exist in both
```

I am using left and right join to do 1) and 2) and inner join for 3). Here are the queries I am using.

```
Query 1) 

select pt.p_id 
from pt left join pf on pt.p_id = pf.p_id and pt.ps_id=1 
where pf.p_id is null
```

Explain output:

```
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref          | rows     | Extra  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pt    | index  | NULL          | p_id       | 100     | NULL         | 19313237 | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pf    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 96      | pt.p_id      | 1        | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
```

This query takes around **300** seconds

```
Query 2)

select pf.p_id 
from pt right join pf on pt.p_id = pf.p_id and pt.ps_id=1 
where pt.p_id is null
```

Explain output:

```
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref         | rows     | Extra                   |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pf     | index  | NULL              | PRIMARY | 96      | NULL        | 19313269 | Using index             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pt     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,p_id      | PRIMARY | 96      | pf.p_id     |        1 | Using where; Not exists |
```

This query takes around **700-1000** seconds

```
Query 3)

select * from pt, pf 
where pt.p_id=pf.p_id 
and pt.ps_id=1
```

This query gives result in milliseconds.

Other Details

Storage engine: MyISAM, RAM: 8G, CPU: I3, CPU Usage while running query: 25%, Total RAM Usage: 4G, MYISAM key buffer: 2G, Application: My application does not need transaction. Mostly huge reads from external systems.

Any help tuning query 1 and query 2 is appreciated.

**Update 1:**

Unfortunately, my table crashed, so had to recreate tables and populate data. 
Here is the current table structure, record count and profile queries. Created new tables pt1 and pf1 containing only columns in question.

**Table definitions**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> describe pt1;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| p_id  | char(32) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ps_id | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [fp1]> describe pf1;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| p_id  | char(32) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Indexes**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> show index from pt1;
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| pt1   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | p_id        | A         |    14170752 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pt1   |          1 | p_id     |            1 | p_id        | A         |    14170752 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pt1   |          1 | p_id     |            2 | ps_id       | A         |    14170752 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [fp1]> show index from pf1;
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| pf1   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | p_id        | A         |    13073810 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Records**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> select count(*) from pt1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 14170752 |
+----------+

MariaDB [fp1]> select count(*) from pf1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 13073810 |
+----------+
```

**Query 1**)

**Query**:

```
select pf1.p_id from pf1 left join pt1 on pf1.p_id = pt1.p_id where pt1.p_id is null;
```

**Records Count**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> select count(pf1.p_id) from pf1 left join pt1 on pf1.p_id = pt1.p_id where pt1.p_id is null;
+-----------------+
| count(pf1.p_id) |
+-----------------+
|         6703180 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (1 min 52.58 sec)
```

**Explain**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> explain select pf1.p_id from pf1 left join pt1 on pf1.p_id = pt1.p_id where pt1.p_id is null;
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows     | Extra
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pf1   | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 96      | NULL            | 13073810 | Using index                          
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pt1   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,p_id  | PRIMARY | 96      | fp1.pf1.p_id    |        1 | Using where; Using index; Not exists
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Show Profile**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> show profile;
+------------------------------+------------+
| Status                       | Duration   |
+------------------------------+------------+
| Sending data                 |   0.006756 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000005 |
| Sending data                 | 118.233962 |
| end                          |   0.000015 |
| query end                    |   0.000005 |
| closing tables               |   0.000003 |
| Unlocking tables             |   0.000011 |
| freeing items                |   0.000007 |
| updating status              |   0.000045 |
| cleaning up                  |   0.000004 |
+------------------------------+------------+
100 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Show Profile extended**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> show profile cpu, block io, swaps for query 1;
| Status                       | Duration   | CPU_user   | CPU_system | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Swaps |
+------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+---------
| Sending data                 |   0.006713 |   0.015600 |   0.000000 |68 |             0 |  NULL |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000006 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| Sending data                 |   0.006843 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |69 |             0 |  NULL |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000005 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| Sending data                 |   0.006756 |   0.015600 |   0.000000 |66 |             0 |  NULL |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000005 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| Sending data                 | 118.233962 | 113.272326 |   3.478822 |994039 |             0 |  NULL |
| end                          |   0.000015 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| query end                    |   0.000005 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| closing tables               |   0.000003 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| Unlocking tables             |   0.000011 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| freeing items                |   0.000007 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| updating status              |   0.000045 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| cleaning up                  |   0.000004 |   0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
100 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Query 2**)

**Query**:

```
select pt1.p_id from pt1 left join pf1 on pt1.p_id=pf1.p_id and pt1.ps_id=1 where pf1.p_id is null;
```

**Records count**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> select count(pt1.p_id) from pt1 left join pf1 on pt1.p_id=pf1.p_id and pt1.ps_id=1 where pf1.p_id is null;
+-----------------+
| count(pt1.p_id) |
+-----------------+
|         7800122 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (59.14 sec)
```

**Explain**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> explain select pt1.p_id from pt1 left join pf1 on pt1.p_id=pf1.p_id and pt1.ps_id=1 where pf1.p_id is null;

| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows     | Extra
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pt1   | index  | NULL          | p_id    | 100     | NULL            | 14170752 | Using index
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pf1   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 96      | fp1.pt1.p_id    |        1 | Using where; Using index; Not exists
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Show Profile**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> show profile;
+------------------------------+-----------+
| Status                       | Duration  |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| Waiting for query cache lock |  0.000006 |
| Sending data                 |  0.002893 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |  0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 62.308426 |
| end                          |  0.000014 |
| query end                    |  0.000004 |
| closing tables               |  0.000003 |
| Unlocking tables             |  0.000009 |
| freeing items                |  0.000007 |
| updating status              |  0.000023 |
| cleaning up                  |  0.000006 |
+------------------------------+-----------+
```

**Show profile extended**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> show profile cpu, block io, swaps for query 1;
| Status                       | Duration  | CPU_user  | CPU_system | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Swaps |
| Sending data                 |  0.003193 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |68 |0|NULL|
| Waiting for query cache lock |  0.000004 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |0 |  NULL |
| Sending data                 | 62.308426 | 57.423968 |   3.993626 |1056787 |0 |  NULL |
| end                          |  0.000014 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |0 |  NULL |
| query end                    |  0.000004 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |0 |  NULL |
| closing tables               |  0.000003 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |0 |  NULL |
| Unlocking tables             |  0.000009 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |0 |  NULL |
| freeing items                |  0.000007 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |0 |  NULL |
| updating status              |  0.000023 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |0 |  NULL |
| cleaning up                  |  0.000006 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |0 |  NULL |
+------------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------
```

**Query 3**

**Query**

```
select pt.p_id from pt1, pf1 where pt1.p_id=pf1.p_id and pt1.ps_id=1
```

**Record count**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> select count(pt1.p_id) from pt1, pf1 where pt1.p_id=pf1.p_id and pt1.ps_id=1;
+-----------------+
| count(pt1.p_id) |
+-----------------+
|         6370630 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (55.69 sec)
```

**Explain**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> explain select pt1.p_id from pt1, pf1 where pt1.p_id=pf1.p_id and pt1.ps_id=1;
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows     | Extra                    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pt1   | index  | PRIMARY,p_id  | p_id    | 100     | NULL            | 14170752 | Using where; Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pf1   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 96      | fp1.pt1.p_id    |        1 | Using index              |
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Profile**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> show profile;
+------------------------------+-----------+
| Status                       | Duration  |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| Waiting for query cache lock |  0.000004 |
| Sending data                 |  0.003548 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |  0.000004 |
| Sending data                 | 57.530804 |
| end                          |  0.000015 |
| query end                    |  0.000006 |
| closing tables               |  0.000004 |
| Unlocking tables             |  0.000010 |
| freeing items                |  0.000009 |
| updating status              |  0.000044 |
| cleaning up                  |  0.000005 |
+------------------------------+-----------+
100 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

**Extended profile**:

```
MariaDB [fp1]> show profile cpu, block io, swaps for query 1;
| Status                       | Duration  | CPU_user  | CPU_system | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Swaps |
| Sending data                 |  0.003303 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| Waiting for query cache lock |  0.000003 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| Sending data                 | 57.530804 | 56.690763 |   0.670804 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| end                          |  0.000015 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| query end                    |  0.000006 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| closing tables               |  0.000004 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| Unlocking tables             |  0.000010 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| freeing items                |  0.000009 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| updating status              |  0.000044 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
| cleaning up                  |  0.000005 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |0 |             0 |  NULL |
100 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note: I had to remove some rows from show profile output (containing time in milliseconds in sending data state) due to limitation of the stackoverflow input limit.

Thanks again for the time everyone spent in looking into the problem, providing suggestions/comments.

Comment: Does p_id have index on it ?

Comment: p_id is a primary key in both the tables. Does it help to add separate index of it in both the tables?

Comment: So query 3 is all right?

Comment: Saw your explain plan, you have index on both p_id.

Comment: @strawberry, My apologies, forgot to mention that in question. Yes, 3 is alright. It gives result in milliseconds.

Comment: Your 2 indexes alone take up about 4GB space (consider different ids or more ram). Just reading them completely from hard drive would require more than some milliseconds for your third query, unless you have e.g. completely different values, so they only have to be completely read for your first 2 queries (e.g.: table 1: ids 1...19.000.000, table 2: 18.999.999..40.000.000). How many rows do you get for your queries? Use `select count(*)` to compare execution time without retrieving all rows. If you have a significant amount of rows with `p_id <> 1`, you could try to add an index `pt(p_id)`.

Comment: @Solarflare, thanks for your comments. How many rows match depends on the ps_id. At most, half the number i.e. around 8 millions. I tried specifying limit 1 but did not make any difference.Tried adding separate index but same result. I increased key buffer to 4G with same results. Btw, I am using SSD if that information is useful in anyway.

Comment: The result count was meant for the queries as written there (for which you gave the timings). If `limit 1` (for these queries without `order by` or anything) doesn't change anything this would be really strange. It would only need to find one not matching row and exit. Can you add an execution profile to see where time went? `set profiling=1; <your queries>; show profiles; show profile cpu, block io, swaps for query xx; (xx the id of your querys as listed in "show profiles", for all 3 separately); set profiling=0;` Did it use the separate index? Try forcing it (or check `explain`).

Comment: @Solarflare, thanks again. You were spot on. Limiting the number indeed return within milliseconds. I might have made some mistake first time. See the update question for the details you have asked.

Comment: What is the ps_id? How much its cardinality? If its cardinality is low then indexing it will not speed up the query so much.

Comment: @Msf vtp, ps_id is source identifier. It can have any of the total 20 given values.

Comment: @rahimv then its cardinality is low and indexing it cannot improve performance so much.

Comment: I recommend partitioning based on ps_id field.

Comment: I think the 3rd query will take long time. To test it run this query `select * from (...query3...)`. Because mysql workbench show first row fetch time and append `limit 1000` to end of the query.

Comment: @minus voter: What i do not understand is why would this well researched, well formatted and perfectly valid question gets minus vote? What do you consider as valid question.

Comment: @Msfvtp, I am not DB expert, but show index shows cardinality as 14170752 (which is equal to total number of records). The index is on (p_id, ps_id).

Comment: @rahimv Thanks for adding the profiles. These timings look more reasonable and query 3 takes similarly long as 1 and 2 now, not just milliseconds. Basically all the time is spend reading the data - as I said about 4GB, that means an average speed of 30-50MB/s (with an ssd you should get more, but it sounds reasonable, and you have limited ram). I guess the best you can do is reorganize your `p_id`-column to reduce the 4GB - e.g.: maybe no utf_8, maybe use varchar, maybe replace them by an integer and save the original id to another table. But that depends on what you are doing with your data.

Comment: @Solarflare, thanks for the comment. Yes, this could be it. When I run the query, I could see the disk usage spikes in the resource monitor. I will have to implement the possible solutions suggested by you to see if it improves the run time. Changing to latin1 is looks like first feasible thing to do. I will report back the results as soon as I can.

Comment: @rahimv no composite index cannot be used when criteria is on the second field. You must create another index on ps_id only.

Comment: @Msfvtp, oh I understood. I will drop the existing one, create separate index and see if it makes any difference. I will also try to see the partition suggestion and report back the results.